# Is there anything wrong with my raspberry (heritage everbearing, zone 7)

Tags: diseases

I'm trying to find out if there is something wrong with my raspberry plant. I was gifted with this plant about two weeks ago. It did have some damaged canes which had to be cut away, but I do not remember making this cut as I would not have cut it at an angle like that. I'm honestly leaning towards cane blight or spur blight, but I want to rule out normal dieback (it IS almost September). We HAVE had a lot of rain and the plant is currently in a pot (we do plan on moving it). Please advise on control/removal of the diseased cane, if that is the case. Thank you in advance.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid this does not look like normal die back - the shoot top right seems too healthy in such circumstances and whatever it is has gone below the shoot below that. I suspect [*Xenodidymella applanata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenodidymella_applanata) against which the [RHS](https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?PID=267) recommends:

> **Non-chemical control**
>
> - Avoid overcrowding by thinning out any young canes that are not required.  This should be done as early in the spring as possible
> - Avoid the over-application of nitrogen
> - If spur blight develops, cut out and dispose of badly affected canes
> - Choose resistant cultivars. The cultivars ‘Glen Lyon’, ‘Glen Moy’, ‘Glen Rosa’, ‘Julia’, ‘Leo’ and ‘Malling Admiral’ have some resistance to spur blight
>
> **Chemical control**
>
> No fungicides are available to home gardeners for the control of raspberry spur blight.

Comment: So I should cut below where that goes? Meaning below where the canker is? How far?

Comment: I did that sulfur might help...would this be helpful or hurtful?https://www.walmart.com/ip/Safer-Brand-32-fl-oz-Ready-to-Use-Garden-Fungicide/19685014

Comment: Well, let me put it this way. My understanding of guitar and cars is better than my understanding of raspberries. My basic guitar knowledge is budding, my understanding of cars is okay (but I have to ask my cousin the professional mechanic for more advanced advice) and my knowledge of raspberries is nil. So yours is better than mine ;)

Comment: FYI I did cut that one cane back to about two inches above the ground...and sprayed with a fungicide with sulfur (we'll see if it works)...and then it rained an hour and a half later...heavily :(

Comment: I can't do that...my mom gifted me with the plant. It's got two healthy canes left so I'm hoping that it doesn't spread to the other two. It was struggling when she found it, but it was the best one left. I figure on giving it my best shot and if it doesn't work...well, she told me she wouldn't be losing much on it.